# Android Cordova WebView

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordovawebview

I am new to `Cordova android development`.
I want to open the specified URLs within the application instead of opening up it in browser.
I know I have to use `WebView` but I need help for how to use the `WebView`.
How to implement `Cordova WebView` for `cordova` android application?

Comment: use InAppBrowser plugin for opening external sites

Answer (score 0):

We don't need to take an any external `webview`. Your complete cordova app will run by default in webview and URL directly will load into webview.

To redirect URL use,

```
location.href = "pageName.html";
```

OR

load page like

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: but first you must whitelisting your website in config.xml

Comment: yes that's your home page. In cordova default page is index.html in config.xml